# Onclick listener for Notification buttons in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have created a notification with a button for API versions more than 16.

Notification and button are coming up properly. I would like to dismiss the notification on clicking the button or notification.

On clicking the notification the notificiation gets cleared but it is not the same when I click on the button it doesn't do anything.

I am not sure how to listen to button click on Notification? Can somebody help me fix this?

[image]

Look at the screen shot... So when I click on AndroidProject - The notification is cleared and an intent is called accordingly, but when I click on Close or the red X mark notification is still there but intent is called. How do I implement to clear notification when I click on the close or X button?

Here is what I have tried:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ServicetocancelAlarm.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
Resources res = context.getResources();

Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.cancelText))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.ticker))
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.cancel, "DISMISS", contentIntent).build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you called notify on the notification manager you gave it an id - that is the unique id you can use to access it later (this is from the notification manager:

```
notify(int id, Notification notification)
```

for cancel

```
cancel(int id)
```

read below link:-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html

[Dismiss Ongoing Android Notification Via Action Button Without Opening App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739371/dismiss-ongoing-android-notification-via-action-button-without-opening-app)

Comment: I didn't understand your answer... The problem here that I have explained is: When I touch the notification - the notification gets cancelled but when I touch dismiss button the notification is not getting cancelled but just stays there. how do I cancel it when I click on the button?

Comment: Please check my screen shot.

Comment: @TheDevMan have u seen link ?

Comment: I have implemented it similar way. THat is why I am saying when I click on the "AndroidProject" notification gets cleared and intent is called accordingly..but when I click DISMISS or RED ICON the intent is called accordingly but the notification is not getting cleared...

Comment: @TheDevMan PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT cancel the current task as per my knowledge and show we your (ServicetocancelAlarm) BroadcastReceiver

Comment: I solved it. The notification ID was the problem instead "007", I had 0. Thanks anyways @Golu...