# Android: Status bar slider

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-statusbar, root-access

I'd like to know if it is possible in Android 5 to include a slider (an app) into the status bar f.e. to adjust brightness, volume etc.?
There are apps like Play Music which also provide a ui in the status bar?

Comment: you could provide your own statusbar. So it definitely is possible.

Comment: @DanielBo hey, thank you for your input. yes, I already thought of that but the OS is a custom ROM and it would be sad to lose the default status bar with it's great features. Still possible anyhow?

Comment: after a quick google search i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377760/adding-spinner-to-actionbar-not-navigation - from what i understand, you can provide your own code from a view inside the Actionbar, which means you may be able to add a slider.

Comment: thank you for your answer but this seems to be only for the action bar inside an activity and unfortunately not for the status bar.

Comment: my bad, i misread you question and just assumed you mean the actionbar.

Comment: @DanielBo I cannot find anything about the status bar. So far I don't think it is possible to add anything to it... although Play Music does it as well, maybe it's a native integration

Comment: can you make a screenshot? i have checked google play app but i cant figure out what it is you mean. only thing i can find is a notification which allows starting/pausing and going to next/previous track

Comment: @DanielBo yeah, I exactly mean the control which you can use to go to the next/prev track. Can this be integrated using a notification? Hmm this could actually be possible :) . But how to achieve that it stays there? I'll have a deeper look into it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dismiss Ongoing Android Notification Via Action Button Without Opening App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739371/dismiss-ongoing-android-notification-via-action-button-without-opening-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at Sticky Notifications, like this: http://www.laurivan.com/android-make-your-notification-sticky/

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html - this explains how to add controls to the notification. But due to its implementation i assume its not possible to add an actual slider, but you could go for +/- buttons.

Comment: Hey this looks great. I'll have a look at it. I hope it is possible to add a slider to it (?). Thank you for your time!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Really appreciate it. It seems not to be possible to add a slider but to use buttons is a good idea!

Comment: Daniel, do you know if it is possible with a rooted device?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as the api doesnt change, i dont think so. Maybe if you can provide your own implementation for the notification center? Not sure if that actually possible