# How to close the notification dialog after click the dismiss button ,without calling any activity

Tags: android, android-layout, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMoag.png)
i have the code. which is working fine and also close the notification. but when i am click on the "dismiss" button, then it open the application and close the dialog. which is not required to me. Actually i want, the notification dialog close after click on the "DISMISS"  button without opening any activity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    static int numMessages = 0;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notificationmain);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        Button bcustomnotifyaction = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.customnotificationaction);

        bcustomnotifyaction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CustomNotificationAction();

            }
        });

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void CustomNotificationAction() {
        // Set Notification Title
        String strtitle = "You Got New Notification.";
        // Set Notification Text
        String strtext ="Hi,How are You?";

        // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
        // Send data to NotificationView Class
        intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);
        intent.putExtra("text", strtext);
        // Open NotificationView.java Activity
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        int notificationId = new Random().nextInt(); // just use a counter in some util class...
        PendingIntent dismissIntent = NotificationActivity.getDismissIntent(notificationId, getApplicationContext());

        //Create Notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                // Set Icon
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logosmall)
                // Set Ticker Message
                .setTicker(strtitle)
                // Set Title
                .setContentTitle(strtitle)
                // Set Text
                .setContentText(strtext)
                // Add an Action Button below Notification
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Dismiss", dismissIntent)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details, "Info", pIntent)
                // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                // showing action button on notification
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setWhen(0)

                /* Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives */
                .setNumber(++numMessages)

                // Dismiss Notification
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        // Create Notification Manager
        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Build Notification with Notification Manager
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

    } 
}
```

**notificationmain.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".NotificationView" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/customnotificationaction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/customnotificationaction" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**NotificationView.java**

```
public class NotificationView extends Activity {
String title;
String text;
TextView txttitle;
TextView txttext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notificationview);

    // Create Notification Manager
    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Dismiss Notification
    notificationmanager.cancel(0);

    // Retrive the data from MainActivity.java
    Intent i = getIntent();

    title = i.getStringExtra("title");
    text = i.getStringExtra("text");

    // Locate the TextView
    txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    txttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    // Set the data into TextView
    txttitle.setText(title);
    txttext.setText(text);
}
}
```

**notificationview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbltitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lbltitle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbltext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lbltitle"
    android:text="@string/lbltext" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbltitle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbltext" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**NotificationActivity.java**

```
public class NotificationActivity extends Activity {

public static final String NOTIFICATION_ID = "NOTIFICATION_ID";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(0);
    finish(); // since finish() is called in onCreate(), onDestroy() will be called immediately
}

public static PendingIntent getDismissIntent(int notificationId, Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
    PendingIntent dismissIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    return dismissIntent;
} 
}
```

**Solution:**

***I got my solution  by using broadcast Receiver .***

CODE i changed :
I added this code in **MainActivity.java** CustomNotificationAction() .

```
//Create an Intent for the BroadcastReceiver
        Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(context, ButtonReceiver.class);
        //Create the PendingIntent
        PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, buttonIntent,0);
```

**And Changed this line From**

```
 .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Dismiss", dismissIntent)
```

**To**

```
.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Dismiss", btPendingIntent)
```

**And Added one Java File**

**ButtonReceiver.java**

```
public class ButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Notification Dialog Closed",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Notification:","Notification Dialog Closed");
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(0);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,  0, new Intent(), 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mb.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
}
}
```

And **Register Broadcast  in Mainfest file**

```
 <receiver android:name=".ButtonReceiver"/>
```

**And my problem Solved :)**

You can also download the source code from this link :

[Download Source Code](https://priyanka-mohanty.github.io/Android-Custom-Notification/)

Answer (score 2):

should set broadcast receiver to detect your action click without starting activity.

[Dismiss Ongoing Android Notification Via Action Button Without Opening App](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19745745/4685284)

Comment: i have 2 action button "dismiss" and "info". for info i will open one activity where showing some message, for "dismiss" button i want notification dialog will dismiss without opening activity :/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with both service and Broadcast receiver , But I think Broadcast receiver would be a better choice to do it.

```
 int final MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

        //Create an Intent for the BroadcastReceiver
        Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(context, AutoDismissReceiver.class);
        buttonIntent.putExtra("notificationId",MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);

           //Create the PendingIntent
        PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, buttonIntent,0);

       //Pass this PendingIntent to addAction method of Intent Builder
        NotificationCompat.Builder mb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
        .....
        .....
        mb.addAction(R.drawable.ic_dismiss, "Dismiss Action", btPendingIntent);
        manager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, mb.build());
```

And Broadcast receiver  for  above function

```
  public class AutoDismissReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                manager.cancel(notificationId);
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps you.