# Close notification from notification bar with a button without opening the app aga

Tags: android, android-notifications

```
public void addnotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mbuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    mbuilder.setContentTitle("Notification");
    mbuilder.setContentText("hi there");
    mbuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mbuilder.setOngoing(true);
    mbuilder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "close", pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)
    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, mbuilder.build());
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager)
    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
    nMgr.cancel(0);
    finish();
}
```

The close button closes all notifications but while closing the notifications it opens the app again.

What I want is when I click on it it should remove the notification but should not open the app, it should stay in the same screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dismiss Ongoing Android Notification Via Action Button Without Opening App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739371/dismiss-ongoing-android-notification-via-action-button-without-opening-app)