# Multiple Notification with dismiss notification action button

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have an app which associates some entities with a unique ID and notifies about the entities to the user, which I'm gonna use notificationID to be the same as entity ID.

I have built a notification with a dismiss action based on the following [sample solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19745745/10317531) exactly without any modification.

So far things are going well until I try to create 2 notifications with different ID using the sample.
A problem arises in that the dismiss button only receives the notificationID of the first notification:

The first notification behaves normally as expected.

But the second notification's `getExtra()` in BroadcastReceiver takes the notificationID of the FIRST notification instead and cancelling the notification just keeps cancelling the first notification.

My create Notification function, I just call this function twice with different IDs:

```
void createNoti(int NOTIFICATION_ID){

    Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(context, ButtonReceiver.class);
    buttonIntent.putExtra("notificationId", NOTIFICATION_ID);

    PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, buttonIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mb = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
    mb.addAction(R.drawable.ic_Action, "My Action", btPendingIntent);
    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mb.build());
}
```

BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class ButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(notificationId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is in passing in `0` into PendingIntent:

```
PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, buttonIntent, 0);
```

I had the same issue until I started passing in the notification id as the 2nd argument; so instead of passing in `0`, pass in the id of the notification:

```
PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_ID, buttonIntent, 0);
```

After I made that change, I noticed that when clicking on individual notifications (especially notifications in a group) everything worked as intended.