# how to Hide notification after tap in android application

Tags: android, notifications

This is the code that gives notification on start of service

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mbuild = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());

Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent resultIN =   PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),code,in,NOTIFICATION_COUNT);           mbuild.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.images1);    
mbuild.setContentText(NOTIFICATION_COUNT +" New Message");
mbuild.setContentIntent(resultIN);          //mbuild.addAction(R.drawable.notifications,NOTIFICATION_COUNT +"New Messages",resultIN);

 NotificationManager nmagr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nmagr.notify(1, mbuild.build());
```

everyting is working correct ..the code opens the target activity but the notification still stays there in the notification bar.
i have tried useing mbuil.setautocancel(true); but its doing nothing

Comment: `mbuild.setAutoCancel(true)`

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883534/how-to-dismiss-android-notification-after-action-has-been-clicked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
NotificationManager nmagr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notification=mbuild.build();
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            nmagr.notify(1,notification);
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set [setAutoCancel(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setAutoCancel%28boolean%29)

Just set this

```
mbuild.setAutoCancel(true)
```

**or**

```
mbuild.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
```

**Updated**

You can also try below code.

```
NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mgr.cancel(1); // here is "1" is your notification id which you set at "nmagr.notify(1, mbuild.build());"
```

write above code in your `onCreate()` method of `MainActivity.class`.

Comment: i have tried mbuild.setAutoCancel(true); .. its not doing anything

Answer (score 1):

```
NotificationManager notification_manager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                notification_manager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Comment: if i use notification_manager.cancel(id) jst below ma code i.e after nmagr.notify(1, mbuild.build());  it cancels the notification by itself before leting the notification cheked or tapped

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to anyone doing this with NotificationCompat and / or using the Notificaitoncompat.Builder.

This is how I did mine :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

builder.setContentTitle(title);

/* your own code here */

builder.setAutoCancel(true); 

Notification notification = builder.build();
NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0,notification);
```

It is important to note that if you use a pending intent to redirect the user to a specific intent in your app, this will also call the pending intent.

As per the documentation :

> Setting this flag will make it so the notification is automatically canceled when the user clicks it in the panel. The PendingIntent set with setDeleteIntent will be broadcast when the notification is canceled.