# Is there a way to show a Push Notification like an iOS banner?

Tags: android, push-notification

[image]I want to show a Push Notification as a banner in my Cordova-based app. When the app is in background by default on Android 5.0.1 when a Push Notification is received it gets added to the notification area. But is there any way to show it as a banner like Facebook or Whatsapp notifications?

Comment: Thanks Idan for the edit

Comment: are you talking about in-app messaging?

Comment: No I am talking about the banner notification that is displayed when there is a new Facebook notification e.g when someone comments on any of your Facebook posts.

Comment: It seems like a native feature as it seems to be there for all my android applications but doesnt happen when I receive a push notification from my mobilefirst server.

Comment: Maybe a Android Lock Screen Widget? you would like to display the contents of the notification in your lock screen?

Comment: Can you attach a sample image of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is library you can use [TSnackBar](https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar) in this place

Actually this is modified SnackBar found in support-design. It comes from top you can make it look like iOS banner notification.
Hope this will look and feel the same.
For Lollipop and above read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27083833/5710872)