# How to clear notification on notification action click?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm developing an android app where I display notifications with actions. But on action click notification not clearing, It stuck in that shade. How do I clear a notification on action click?

**MY CODE**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
PendingIntent openSettingsActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_notification_button, "Settings", openSettingsActivity);
notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
                notificationBuilder.setContentText(text);
                notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                notificationBuilder.setColor(color);
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(openSettingsActivity);
                final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1,notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883534/how-to-dismiss-notification-after-action-has-been-clicked

Comment: No, that doesn't helping me

Answer (score -1):

Hiding notifications should be processed in the place where the intent is sent.
In your current code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("hide_notification", true); //add boolean to check later in activity if it should remove notification on activity create
```

And in your activity smth like this, to check if it should remove notification:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //check for notification remove
        boolean hideNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("hide_notification", false);
        if (hideNotification) {
            NotificationManagerCompat nmc = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            nmc.cancel(1); //1 - is your notification id
        }
    }
```

Depends on what you want, maybe it will be better to call that not in `onCreate()` but `onStart()`